# Has exceed the max_user_connection_resource (current value:10)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, signalr

I have created .netcore application and I have use dependency injection to inject dbcontext to use. I know that this type error is showing me because some dbcontext haven't destroyed and reach the max db connections. Do I need to manually dispose dbcontext that have use. I have seen that when using dependency injections we don't need to destroy them manually and they will destroy automatically.Is this right?

Other question is that I have use SingnalR and used Hub.Context to fetch current user details for an example

```
var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

The context I have created is

```
MainDbContext _bdcontext = new MainDbContext();
```

and I have use DP to inject _dbcontext

I need to know that is this Hub.context and _bdcontext are same and do I need to manually destroy Hub.context or are those Hub.context destroy manually.

my 3rd question is if a user close the browser or internet connection drop is the allocated dbcontext destroy?

my 4th question is that is there any tool or any way to check not destroyed dbcontext connections.

I have share my ChatHub file and I can't find why this error is showing

https://drive.google.com/open?id=172AScIz0h4kbol6W8hPyoebq9jocfzH2

Answer (score 0):

Without a complete, minimal, veryfiable example, it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong. However I do have one rule on this mater:

"Never split up the creation and disposing of a disposeable resource. Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)."

There are some rare exceptions, but I seriously doubt you have any of those. Especially do not split it up for performance reasons - if it maters, those classes will have some internal conneciton pooling. Also speed optimisation is way to early, if you code does not work yet.

Comment: Hi Christopher I have share the file that in google drive you can check it. Can you tell me is Hub.context and the context we create is the same and do we need to manually dipose Hub.context or it will dispose itself automatically

Comment: @JanithaKalshan That file is to big by an oder of magnitude. Nobody is going to look through your entire codebase. Make a **minimal**, complete, verifyable example. You either figure the issue out while doing so, or can at least give us a simple example that we can follow. | Just a minor warning, that you should actually do something that can have a effect in the loops. If you just open the files without doing anything, chances are good the JiT will detect it as dead code and cut it out.